# set line space for \newcommand

Tags: macros, graphics, captions, line-spacing

I added a \newcommand, "Source", for adding the source of a figure after its caption. However, I found some problem of adjusting the space between the source and the caption. My code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\graphicspath{{./images/}}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\newcommand{\source}[1]{\caption*{Source: {#1}}}  % define a new style of caption, "source"
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{DS products & service.png}
    \caption{Some products and services 3DS provides}
    \source{Dassault systèmes website, \url{https://www.3ds.com/products-services/}}
    \label{fig:prodService}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And the result is like the following picture. The line space pointed by the red arrow is too wide, how should I adjust it?
[image]

Comment: In most recommendations I've seen such information is included in the actual caption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some negative vertical space in the definition of `\source`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=1cm,right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25} 
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}  
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\newcommand{\source}[1]{\vspace{-1Em}\caption*{Source: {#1}}}  % define a new style of caption, "source"
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{DS products & service.png}
    \caption{Some products and services 3DS provides}
    \source{Dassault systèmes website, \url{https://www.3ds.com/products-services/}}
    \label{fig:prodService}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `caption` package, more sensible approach would be using `\captionsetup` inside your `\souce` macro to remove the spacing.

```
\newcommand{\source}[1]{\captionsetup{aboveskip=0pt}\caption*{Source: {#1}}}
```

So instead of eyeballing the `\vspace` to make it look ok, the presented approach will work despite on the global spacing settings.